# Append mouseover event to img in a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append a mouseover event to an image in a div with jQuery.
Here is how I append the imgs to the div. This is my code, appending the img and the href to the div. Now, I want the mouseover. So far I have tried a lot of things, which simply did not work, like trying to append a function ...

```
for (var index in obj){                 
    $("#my_div").append($("<a>", 
    {
        href: urlSite, 
        html: $("<img>", { src: avatar }),
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jquery `on` function to add handlers to events like so

```
$('#your_image_id').on('mouseover', function() {
    console.log('hello');
});
```

**Edit**

To do it dynamically:

```
$('#my_div').append($('<img>').attr('src', avatar).on('mouseover', function() {
    console.log('hello');
}));
```

***Edit2***

```
for (var index in obj){                 
    $("#my_div").append($("<a>", 
    {
        href: urlSite, 
        html: $("<img>", { src: avatar }),
    }).mouseover(function() {
        $('#my_other_div').append($(this).attr('href')); 
    })); 
}
```

Comment: Hi. The point is that I do not have ids, as I am trying to do it dynamically.

Comment: Seems nice, but is there a way to do it my way? Like to append everything at once to the div - the event, the img and the link?

Comment: Yup, easy enough. Updated. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that you can assign event handlers using the object notation that you've specified though

Comment: Why would you want an href on an img? Should we move this to a chat as the comments are getting a bit long :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102851/discussion-between-vityata-and-ryuu).